# On a roster hide dates already past

Tags: vba, show-hide, group

I was given a roster in a worksheet with Monday starting in C1 going to Sunday in AG1, then Monday + 7 starting in C30. This number is changeable depending on staff members.
I want to achieve that by clicking a button on a different worksheet, it takes the date out of B2 (which should be a Monday - achieved error message), finds that date (I can do so in excel, not sure in VBA) and hides all rows beforehand.
I'm aware of grouping and can apply grouping (for the first instance). What makes my scenario more complicated is that the roster is already grouped (for printing purposes) which I can't/ don't want to lose.
How can I help it, that it doesn't delete any first instance grouping.
It also doesn't go to the roster worksheet (yet), but groups on the worksheet the button is on.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'check if date is a Monday
If Weekday(Range("B2").Value) <> 2 Then
    MsgBox "Please alter the date to a Monday.", 0, "Date selected is not a Monday."
    Exit Sub
End If
'find row
Dim Hrange As String
Hrange = "1:" & Range("C41").Value
Sheets("Roster2023").Activiate 'doesn't go to roster
Rows(Hrange).Group
'MsgBox Hrange
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8
'MsgBox Hrange
End Sub
```

Comment: could you post images of the before and and expected result?

Comment: I read carefully your question twice, but i could not understand too much... Does "then Monday + 7 starting in C30" be translated as "Add 7 days to Date extracted from C1 and place it **on the cell bellow the last existing in C:C**? Or **the last row of column C:C should contain a Date, bigger with a week against C1 Date value**? Or wat? Then, the scene should be moved "in another sheet", "takes the date out of B2", " finds that date and hides all rows beforehand". **Where to find the respective Date**? In the previous mentioned sheet? If so, in which column? C:C?

Comment: Then, apocalyptically finishing with "but groups on the worksheet the button is on"... What should that mean, please? To group anything on the second (secret) sheet? If so, **what to be grouped**? Editing your question, showing some pictures, as required above, and focusing of a better description of what you try accomplishing, will surely help us understanding what you try doing. Otherwise, I am afraid that we cannot help you even if we want to...

Comment: Not sure what you want to do but change ```Sheets("Roster2023").Activiate``` to ```Sheets("Roster2023").Activate``` and it will activate the sheet. Just a simple spelling error. The rest of the question is quite unclear.